# Magento : Hide admin side menu "mobile" inside custom plugin

Tags: php, xml, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.8

I had to hide Some menus in Admin side.

I refered **MANY** questions here on Stackoverflow , on other sites .  BUT they simply say ,

`Create a file called adminhtml.xml under /etc folder of your module:`

BUT no one told what should be in module , will it have class , what should be in it????

Lets take it easy :

I hav all folders like ,controller,Model .. In folder `local\MyCompanyName\WelcomeInsync`
NOW WHAT ?

I simply created adminhtml.xml in etc folder but NOTHING happened

I used following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <xmlconnect> <!-- <xmlconnect> to match adminhtml.xml file of Mage_XmlConnect module -->
            <depends>
                <module>HideMe</module> <!-- Fake dependance to hide tab -->
            </depends>
        </xmlconnect>
    </menu>
</config>
```

What should be done ? I have folders only blank ,just etc has files config.xml + adminhtml.xml.

I tried cache clearing Nothing Worked . Is there any magento EXPERT to answer ? THANKS!

Comment: Please contact the vendor of your product for your support options, you should get more help there. Your question is most likely a support request and not a programming question. Asking for reference material makes it extra fishy as a bonus as asking for resources is specifically off-topic. If you prefer the Q&A format over the [Magento support forums](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewcategory/8/), the [Magento beta on Stackexchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com/) might be an alternative for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did ,I wanted  to do.

I just Created User with Less permissions , so automatically the menu got hidden .